# Constructing a nested JSON object from a sql query string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, nested, javascript-objects, query-string

I'm trying to construct a nested JSON object from a query string which is returned from sql. The constructed nested JSON object will be be used by angular to render it in the UI using angular2-query-builder.

input_string = "TierLevel = '1' AND CompanyType = '7' AND CompanyService = '23' AND ( City LIKE('%york%') OR City LIKE('%cal%') )  AND ( StateProvince = 3171 OR StateProvince = 475 OR StateProvince = 2239 OR ( Country = 224 AND Country = 1 )  )";

```js
output_JSON_Object = {
    condition: 'and',
    rules: [
        {
            field: 'TierLevel',
            operator: 'Equals',
            value: '1'
        },
        {
            field: 'CompanyType',
            operator: 'Equals',
            value: '7'
        },
        {
            field: 'CompanyService',
            operator: 'Equals',
            value: '23'
        },
        {
            condition: 'or',
            rules: [
                {
                    field: 'City',
                    operator: 'Contains',
                    value: 'york'
                },
                {
                    field: 'City',
                    operator: 'Contains',
                    value: 'cal'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            condition: 'or',
            rules: [
                {
                    field: 'StateProvince',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '3171'
                },
                {
                    field: 'StateProvince',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '475'
                },
                {
                    field: 'StateProvince',
                    operator: 'Equals',
                    value: '2239'
                },
                {
                    condition: 'and',
                    rules: [
                        {
                            field: 'Country',
                            operator: 'Equals',
                            value: '224'
                        },
                        {
                            field: 'Country',
                            operator: 'Equals',
                            value: '1'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What "various approaches" did you try? Don't forget to `JSON.parse()` at the end to get your JSON.

Comment: Hi mykaf. I tried using recursion to get the desired output. But didn't get the required output. JSON.parse() won't work on this input string.

Comment: Oops, I meant JSON.stringify() for your final string. What recursive approach did you take to attempt this? We have no idea where you're going wrong if we can't see any code.

Comment: Do you want to support all SQL syntax or just a small subset? If the former, try using a library. Otherwise, please add your requirements to the question.

Comment: how could `Country = 224 AND Country = 1` ever be true? and if correct, why does this term has and OR operator later?

Comment: @NinaScholz Country = 224 AND Country = 1 is just a rule which will return the search results. You can ignore the logic here. I just wanted to build a json object out of the query string.

Comment: Are "Equals" and "Contains" the only two operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example contains all the possible variations in operators and literals, then you could use this parse function:

```js
function parseExpression(expr) {
    const tokens = expr.matchAll(/(\S\w*)(?:\s*(=|LIKE)\(?\s*('(?:[^']|'')*'|[-\d.]+)\)?)?/g);
    
    function getRule() {
        const {value: [all, field, operator, literal]} = tokens.next();
        return all == "(" 
            ? getExpression()
            : {
                field,
                operator: operator == "=" ? "Equals"
                        : literal[1] != "%" ? "Ends With"
                        : literal.at(-2) != "%" ? "Begins With"
                        : "Contains",
                value: literal[0] != "'" ? +literal
                     : (operator == "LIKE" ? literal.replaceAll("%", "") : literal)
                       .slice(1, -1).replaceAll("''", "'")
            };
    }
    
    function getExpression() {
        const obj = { operator: null, rules: [getRule()] };
        for (let {done, value} = tokens.next(); !done && value[0] != ")"; {done, value} = tokens.next()) {
            obj.operator = value[0].toLowerCase();
            obj.rules.push(getRule());
        }
        return obj;
    }
    
    return getExpression();
}

// Example run
const input = "TierLevel = '1' AND CompanyType = '7' AND CompanyService = '23' AND ( City LIKE('york%') OR City LIKE('%cal') OR City LIKE('%any%') ) AND ( StateProvince = 3171 OR StateProvince = 475 OR StateProvince = 2239 OR ( Country = 224 AND Country = 1 ) )";

const output = parseExpression(input);
console.log(output);
```

The parser has no error handling and assumes the input has the expected syntax. For instance:

- The `LIKE` argument is expected to have at least one `%`, and only at the start and/or at the end of the string literal and no other wildcards, so that indeed it can be identified as a "Contains", "Begins With" or "Ends With" operation.
- There is no support for `<=`, `IN` or other operators
- The conditions are always in the form `field operator literal`, where the literal can have parentheses around it (as for `LIKE`)
- Spacing around `(` and `)` is guaranteed when not used for `LIKE`.
- The operators that occur in the same sequence are always the same (always AND or always OR), and parentheses are used to group subexpressions that use a different operator.
- ...etc

Extend as needed to support other operators, syntax, and error handling.

Comment: Thanks @trincot. This covers most of the requirement. This is very helpful.  I missed to add operators 'Begins With' and 'Ends With'. How can we handle these two operators.  example_input_string = "Name LIKE('%containsA%') OR City = 'equalsB' OR PostalCode LIKE('beginsWithC%') OR Name LIKE('%endsWithD')"

Comment: Updated with support for Begins With, Ends With

Comment: Hi @trincot. Is there a way where I can replace while(true) with any other valid condition. Because eslint is throwing 'Unexpected constant condition.eslintno-constant-condition' error if I use while(true).

Comment: OK, I revamped the code to turn the `while(true)` loop into a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [antlr](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) to break down your input sql string into tokens and later based on the broken tokens you can construct your required json.

Answer (score 0):

use AST with dfs can help you, i think.